# Mutable variable in class not updating

Tags: swift

I have a class like this:

```
class Animal = {
  var name: String
  var weight: String

  init(name: String, weight: String)

  self.name = name
  self.weight = weight
}
```

And instances like this:

```
let cat = Animal(
  name: "Cat",
  weight: metric ? "1kg" : "2.2 lbs"
)
```

`metric` is a variable I set globally that changes to `true` or `false` depending on user settings.

The problem is that even if `metric` changes, `weight` does not update unless I restart the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have a lot of properties like `weight` and a lot of instances (hundreds) so I'm trying to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either listen to `metric` and change your model accordingly or use a computed property like this to get the `weight` depending upon the up-to-date value of the global variable

```
var weight: String {
   return metric ? "1kg" : "2.2 lbs"
}
```

Comment: But then wouldn't I need to set this for every mutable variable? I have a lot of different class instances each with a lot of similar variables with different values.

Comment: this is less-code approach you need to follow it whatever count of vars you have

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a `Weight` struct that returns `metric` or `imperial` based on inquiry.

```
struct Weight {
    metric: String
    imperial: String
    init(_ metric: String, _ imperial: String) {
        self.metric = metric
        self.imperial = imperial
    }
}
```

Then when you define your `Animal`:

```
let cat = Animal(
  name: "Cat",
  weight: Weight("1kg", "2.2 lbs")
)
```

Then when you inquire about weight:

```
let weight = metric ? cat.weight.metric : cat.weight.imperial
```

You need to set both values - `metric` and `imperial` - if you want to be able to switch freely between the two. (Alternatively, if this is your problem in a literal sense, you could define the metric weight only and then calculate the imperial weight whenever it's requested.)